# Binomial distributions?

Tags: distributions, self-study

Research has shown that people are likely to bypass tomatoes that weigh less than 70 grams. a produce company produces tomatoes that average 78 g with a standard deviation of 5.2 g.

The company claims that the goal of 2% undersized tomatoes is reached. To test this, a random sample of 20 tomatoes is taken. What is the distribution of the number of undersized tomatoes in this sample if the company's claims is true. Explain your reasoning.

So for this question do I just need to state the assumptions for a binomial distribution?

So are the assumptions that there are two outcomes, there is a constant probability, there is a fixed number of trials and that the trials are independent? Is that how you answer this type of question??

THANKS

Comment: You answer this type of question by first identifying what would constitute a valid answer.  As far as I can see, it is requesting "the distribution of the number of undersized tomatoes" along with an account of how you determined it.  Thus, at a minimum you need to specify a distribution for a number that could be 0, 1, ..., 19, or 20.

Answer (score 0):

I'm treating this as a [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study) question, so I'll point you towards how to approach the answer rather than give you the answer.

Distributions are characterized by different parameters. You have been given two such parameters - a mean and a standard deviation (which is the square root of the variance, so you know that too). So types of distributions can be described well by the mean and variance? Well, [the normal distribution](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution.html) (a.k.a. the Gaussian distribution) is completely described by this and seems reasonable for your example.

Knowing the distribution and those two parameters, you can calculate the % of tomatoes that should be above or below any threshold at all, including 70g. You can then compare this calculated percentage to the 2% claimed, which allows you to answer the question.

Comment: @user700564 I've added more detail

Comment: @user700564 Hmmm, I guess I misread your question originally. matteo is right that it answers a slightly different question than the one you posed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that strictly speaking the distribution should be the hypergeometric, since presumably the tomatoes are sampled without replacement. However, since the number of tomatoes produced by the company is likely much larger than 20, the binomial is a good approximation. Accepting the company claim as true, i.e. there's a fixed 0.02 probability that a tomato's size is below the threshold, and the 20 tomatoes are independently drawn, the probability mass function of the binomial distribution gives you the probability that $k$ out of the 20 tomatoes are undersized.

Comment: I'm actually just really confused with what the question is asking. I've talked to some tutors and they're all telling me different things. I'm not sure if I actually have to use a calculation to answer. Any help is really appreciated!! Thanks for taking the time to reply :).

Comment: If the question asked is "What is the distribution of the number of undersized tomatoes in this sample _if the company's claims is true_", as you stated, then you can calculate it using the binomial distribution. Of course, you can also use the numbers given to check whether the claim is true - for example assuming a Gaussian distribution of tomato's size as @mkt  suggested - but that for me would be a different question.

Comment: So would I say this this is binomial distribution because there are two outcomes (the tomato can't be overweight and normal), there is a constant probability and the events are independent? Am I right to say there are not calculations involved?

Comment: Yes, I would say that there are two outcomes (a tomato's size is either below the size threshold, or it is not) so it seems only a matter of applying binomial distribution.